# To get current row ID from asp grid in code behind from LinkButton

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have asp grid like this :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" ShowFooter="false" DataKeyNames="ID" Enabled="false" BorderStyle="solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#ACA899" BackColor="#BFD3EE" CellSpacing="1" GridLines="none">
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductID" Visible="false" HeaderStyle-                  HorizontalAlign="left"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="gvheader" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-Width="40px" >
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:label runat="server" ID="lblProductID" Text='<%#eval("ProductID") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>    
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gvheader" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnShowProductDetails" OnClick="lnkbtnShowProductDetails_Click" runat="server"  Enabled="true">Details</asp:LinkButton>                                                 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And in code behind i have :

```
Sub lnkbtnShowProductDetails_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

How can i get current row's ID (value of datakeynames), I dont want to use command and command argument here.

Please assist me on this !!

Answer (score 3):

You can use below complete solution.

```
protected void lblTicketNumber_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton b = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)b.NamingContainer;
        if (row != null)
        {
           int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;
           string key = LstViewTicket.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to access the data key names

```
Sub lnkbtnShowProductDetails_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   Dim lnkbtnShowProductDetails As LinkButton = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton)
   Dim gridViewRow As GridViewRow = DirectCast(lnkbtnShowProductDetails.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
   Dim val = gv.DataKeys(gridViewRow.DataItemIndex)
   Dim key = gv.DataKeyNames(gridViewRow.DataItemIndex)
End Sub
```